# Popup continues to show 'damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.'

Tags: macos, applications, sonoma

I deleted an app using Appclear. then this popup show up:

**App damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.**

(Move to Trash) or (Cancel)

Whether I click “Move to Trash” or “Cancel” buttons, this popup show up again and again

I tried this command, but it did not work:

```
sudo xattr -rds com.apple.quarantine /Applications/AppName.app
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is nothing to do with quarantine, but is usually because the app's signed status is invalid. (In other words, the app has been modified in some way.)

If deleting an app with a 'cleaning' utility doesn't actually delete the app, then that's something you should ask the developers about; or at least give you pause for thought about whether to trust such apps.

You could see if the app will delete after a restart; otherwise, try deleting it in Terminal with something like:

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/AppName.app
```